# Sql Server query taking too much time

Tags: sql-server

Below query execution takes 45 secs. How to improve the speed?

```
SELECT
    u.i_UserID, 
    u.vch_LoginName,         
    ea.vch_EmailAddress, 
    u.vch_DisplayName,
    'Current' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
FROM
    tblUser u 
    LEFT JOIN [User].dbo.tblEmailAddress ea 
       ON u.i_EmailAddressID = ea.i_EmailAddressID
WHERE
    IsNull(u.vch_LoginName, '') Like '%'
    AND u.vch_DisplayName LIKE 'kala' -- 14 secs

UNION ALL   -- 29 secs

SELECT
    DISTINCT l.i_UserID
    ,l.vch_OldLoginName as vch_LoginName
    ,l.vch_OldEmailAddress as vch_EmailAddress
    ,u.vch_DisplayName as vch_DisplayName,
    'Old' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
FROM tblUserStatusLog l
INNER JOIN tblUser u on u.i_UserID = l.i_UserID
WHERE 
    l.vch_OldLoginName  Like '%'
    AND u.vch_DisplayName LIKE 'kala' -- 28 secs
ORDER BY
    u.vch_LoginName
```

Comment: In order to improve your question, tell us something more about table structure, amount of rows, indexes, machine, etc...

Comment: Most likely you need to improve indexing. If you want more help, include into your question also the create table & index statements, query plan and statistics io output.

Comment: `IsNull(u.vch_LoginName, '') Like '%'` and `l.vch_OldLoginName  Like '%'` doesn't make any sense, what is the use of this ?

Comment: Need to show query plan.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, why are you using `LIKE` to compare strings? `LIKE` is used to compare partially strings, you should use `=` operator to search for exact match.

I also don't understand the first condition on both of the where clauses, are you trying to check they are not empty strings and not null? better of use `IS NOT NULL` and `<>` operator:

```
SELECT
    u.i_UserID, 
    u.vch_LoginName,        
    ea.vch_EmailAddress, 
    u.vch_DisplayName,
    'Current' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
FROM
    tblUser u 
    LEFT JOIN [User].dbo.tblEmailAddress ea ON u.i_EmailAddressID = ea.i_EmailAddressID
WHERE
    u.vch_LoginName is not null and u.vch_loginname <> ''
    AND u.vch_DisplayName = 'kala' 
    UNION ALL   

    SELECT
        DISTINCT l.i_UserID
        ,l.vch_OldLoginName as vch_LoginName
        ,l.vch_OldEmailAddress as vch_EmailAddress
        ,u.vch_DisplayName as vch_DisplayName,
        'Old' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
    FROM tblUserStatusLog l
    INNER JOIN tblUser u on u.i_UserID = l.i_UserID
    WHERE 
        l.vch_OldLoginName <> ''
        AND u.vch_DisplayName = 'kala' 
        ORDER BY
    u.vch_LoginName
```

Other then that, I assume you can significantly improve the performance by adding the proper indexes to the tables, but we will need your table structures for that to see what already exists .

But you should have indexes on `i_EmailAddressID` on first two tables, `i_userId` on the second ones , and an index on `vch_OldLoginName,vch_displayName` might also improve the run.

Comment: Hi,I need  u.vch_LoginName is null values...thats y i put that condition.is there any other way to get null values also

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do, the query I posted doesn't work? @BabuAtcha

Comment: Hi Sagi,Why it takes 25 secs for displaying just 50 records...can you please  correct the query..SELECT   DISTINCT l.i_UserID
   ,l.vch_OldLoginName as vch_LoginName
   ,l.vch_OldEmailAddress as vch_EmailAddress
   ,u.vch_DisplayName as vch_DisplayName,
   'Old' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
  FROM tblUserStatusLog l
  INNER JOIN tblUser u 
  on u.i_UserID = l.i_UserID
  WHERE  
  
  u.vch_DisplayName LIKE 'kala'

Comment: Follow my instructions, add indexes ans use my query and everything will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to take a look at indexing. When you run this query with the actual execution plan switched on do you get any missing query hints? Make sure all indexes are optimised for this query and you'll get much better performance.

You're including the full path for tblEmailAddress, is this stored in another database called 'User'? If so, you'll want to reduce the amount of data you're pulling from the linked server. Again, an index should help you here.

You also don't want to be doing calculations in your where clauses. Check out the SARGability of queries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable This will tell you why your LIKE statements are a bad idea too.

Comment: Hi Benner,Why it takes 25 secs for displaying just 50 records...can you please  correct the query..SELECT   DISTINCT l.i_UserID
   ,l.vch_OldLoginName as vch_LoginName
   ,l.vch_OldEmailAddress as vch_EmailAddress
   ,u.vch_DisplayName as vch_DisplayName,
   'Old' As 'vch_RecordStatus'
  FROM tblUserStatusLog l
  INNER JOIN tblUser u 
  on u.i_UserID = l.i_UserID
  WHERE  
  
  u.vch_DisplayName LIKE 'kala'

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT l.i_UserID ,l.vch_OldLoginName as vch_LoginName ,l.vch_OldEmailAddress as vch_EmailAddress ,u.vch_DisplayName as vch_DisplayName, 'Old' As 'vch_RecordStatus' FROM tblUserStatusLog l INNER JOIN tblUser u on u.i_UserID = l.i_UserID WHERE u.vch_DisplayName LIKE 'kala'

Comment: If you need to add code, edit the question rather than posting it in comments. the only obvious thing is that your LIKE statement should be =. After that, you're going to have to look at the actual execution plan to see what's happening (and check for missing query hints)